# How to close all the browser?

Tags: vbscript

I try to create code which closes/kills all the browsers.
How to do this?

I create code like this:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
obj.Quit

Set obj = CreateObject("Chorme.Application")
obj.Quit

Set obj = CreateObject("Firefox.Application")
obj.Quit
```

but it doesn't work.

Any idea to write script for close the all browser at once? Like we see in CCleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateObject can only be used to operate the COM or ActiveX object, but unluckily Chrome or Firefox is not ActiveX . To work as expected, you can fire with tasklist and taskkill.

Tasklist can list the process name with pid, and taskkill can terminate the process with specified id.

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
iexplore.exe                  2448 Console                    1     63,124 K
iexplore.exe                  2752 Console                    1    304,312 K
iexplore.exe                  4660 Console                    1    230,492 K
iexplore.exe                  1908 Console                    1    211,332 K
iexplore.exe                  4536 Console                    1    148,400 K
iexplore.exe                  3760 Console                    1    136,800 K
iexplore.exe                  3652 Console                    1    206,788 K
iexplore.exe                  2248 Console                    1    198,296 K


taskkill /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe"
```

code in vbs

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("taskkill /fi ""imagename eq iexplore.exe""")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: any other way to close all the browse

Comment: vbscript for click on the close button ??can i click on the specific x y location using vbscript

Comment: taskkill /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe"  , just replace the iexplore.exe with different image.

Comment: can you provide the vb script when i try i have error

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without shelling out:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

browser = "iexplore.exe"
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='" & browser & "'"

For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  p.Terminate
Next
```